# CKEditor - CKFinder won't create thumbnail automatically after i upload image

Tags: php, javascript, ckeditor, ckfinder

In ckeditor ( with ckfinder )

I can upload image normally, but it won't create thumbnail before I click the "Browser Server" button, which means I have to use the browse server function to make it create thumbnail manually.

Is there any way ( PHP ) to define creating thumbnail automatically after I upload image?

Answer (score 1):

Finally i have figured it out and tested the code works fine.

Find the file in ckfinder
ckfinder/core/connector/php/php5/CommandHandler/FileUpload.php

look for the code and change

```
if($_imagesConfig->getMaxWidth()>0&&$_imagesConfig->getMaxHeight()>0&&$_imagesConfig->getQuality()>0){
    CKFinder_Connector_CommandHandler_Thumbnail::createThumb($sFilePath, $sFilePath, $_imagesConfig->getMaxWidth(), $_imagesConfig->getMaxHeight(), $_imagesConfig->getQuality(), true);
}
```

to

```
if($_imagesConfig->getMaxWidth()>0&&$_imagesConfig->getMaxHeight()>0&&$_imagesConfig->getQuality()>0){
    CKFinder_Connector_CommandHandler_Thumbnail::createThumb($sFilePath, $sFilePath, $_imagesConfig->getMaxWidth(), $_imagesConfig->getMaxHeight(), $_imagesConfig->getQuality(), true);

    $_thumbnails=$_config->getThumbnailsConfig();
    $thumbFilePath=$sServerDir.'_thumbs/Images/'.$sFileName;
    CKFinder_Connector_CommandHandler_Thumbnail::createThumb($sFilePath, $thumbFilePath, $_thumbnails->getMaxWidth(), $_thumbnails->getMaxHeight(), $_thumbnails->getQuality(), true, $_thumbnails->getBmpSupported());
}
```

and then it will create thumb file everytime you finish uploading image.